# Multiple row layout Adapter doesn't display correctly

Tags: android, android-viewholder

I'm trying to use `viewType` on my `ViewHolder` to separate the header from the other items. With the code I have currently, the header displays correctly but no other item is displayed below. If I remove the `viewType` condition, all the items display correctly, but, of course, the header doesn't have the desired view).

Here is my adapter code:

```
public class GradelistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private static final int ITEM = 1, HEADER = 0;
    private List<ItemGrade> gradeList;

    public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView course, grade;

        public ItemViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            course = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.course);
            grade = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.grade);
        }
    }

    public class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView header;

        public HeaderViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            header = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.year);
        }
    }

    public GradelistAdapter(List<ItemGrade> gradelist) {
        this.gradeList = gradelist;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (gradeList.get(position).getGrade() == -1) {
            return HEADER;
        }

        return ITEM;
    }


    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        if (viewType == HEADER) {
            View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gradelist_header, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new HeaderViewHolder(header);

        }
        else{
            View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gradelist_row, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(item);

        }

        Log.d("onCreateViewHolder", Integer.toString(viewType));
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ItemGrade entry = gradeList.get(position);
        if (holder.getItemViewType() == HEADER) {
            HeaderViewHolder headerViewHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;
            headerViewHolder.header.setText("Viti " + entry.getYear());
        } else {
            ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
            itemViewHolder.course.setText(entry.getCourse());
            itemViewHolder.grade.setText(Integer.toString(entry.getGrade()));

        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return gradeList.size();
    }
```

Comment: are you sure that getGrade() has -1 value only one time?

Comment: Well, currently yes, cause as you can see on `onCreateViewHolder()`, I print the `viewType` in the logcat and it is correct. The first one is always 0 (header) and the next ones are 1 (items). I put that -1 for testing purposes, the problem isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

This is embarassing. Everything is okay, just my header layout filled the whole screen and I needed to scroll down to see the rest of my list.